# MongoDB find document with Date field using a part of Date

Tags: regex, database, mongodb, mongoose, find

i want to search a date like the following:

```
09-11
03-22
```

and it will search in the available documents and bring the matched documnet.
an available document example :

```
2022-09-11T15:31:25.083+00:00
```

how can i do this?

i tried following query but that didn't work:

```
db.users.find({ createdAt: new RegExp('09-11') }) // Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `aggregate` query:

- `$toString` - to convert date to string
- `$regexMatch` - to apply regex search

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": {
            "$toString": "$createdAt"
          },
          "regex": "09-11"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ow0-YvXIqmJ)

Comment: is it possible to use this in a $or operator ? because there are other fields also and i want to combine this query into other fields query so in this way the search will do once.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: found it by testing in [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/naPbSiiGB0U), thanks for sharing this great site!

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate` you can extract [`$dayOfMonth`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/#-dayofmonth--aggregation-) and [`$month`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#-month--aggregation-) from initial date, filter using`$match` and after `$project` the initial document by excluding calculated day and month from the document.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      month: {
        $month: "$createdAt"
      },
      day: {
        $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      month: 9,
      day: 11
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      month: 0,
      day: 0
    }
  }
])
```